# Selecting faces with Raycaster in ThreeJS with STL Loader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently working on a .stl viewer using Three.js. The goal is select and calculate certain areas.
For this area calculation I need to be able to select (e.g. change the color) faces.

I have found [something similar](https://jsfiddle.net/zgeub59q/1/), but from what I have seen in my own research this only seems to be working with ready made meshes (like the cube in the example).

I am looking to implement this example in my own code.

It is evident that something like this has been done before, but I just can't seem to implement any kind of working way in my own code:

My current code has a fully functional .stl loader and viewer.  <strike>The raycaster is there, but doesn't seem to be working properly so I have commented it out for the moment.</strike> *Mugen87, thank you for the fix!*

You can download [my code and an example .stl file from github](https://github.com/TjalleWired/three.js-stackoverflow). Which only requires a Live Server environment which can easily be ran using VSCode (see readme).

My current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3d viewer tjalle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/render.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script>
        function init() {
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );


            function onMouseMove(event) {
                mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            }

            // Setup some basic stuff
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);


            // Setup Camera 
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);

            // Setup renerer and add to page
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            }

            // Setup Camera Position
            camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
            camera.position.x = 800;
            camera.position.y = 100;
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            // Add Camera Control through orbit.js
            let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // Add some basic ambient lighting (Does light all parts equally and does not cast shadows)
            hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 5.3);
            scene.add(hlight);


            //Add some point lights to simulate real lights
            light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 10000);
            light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
            scene.add(light);

            controls.update();
            // Animation Script
            function animate() {
                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
                scene.children[2].material.color.set(0x1313)
                // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
                for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
                    intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
                }
                

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }

            // Setup GLTF Loader and load in car
            let loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load('../converter/output/output.stl', function (geometry) {

                // console.log(gltf);
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0x1313,
                    wireframe: false
                });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);

                scene.add(mesh);
                renderer.render(scene, camera)
                animate();
                console.log("SCene: ", )
            });


        }

        // Call method for starting init
        init();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only selecting faces with use of a raycaster (which was my question), can be done by reading out the `intersects` data from the raycaster. Which gives you the ability to manipulate the face, thus 'select' it.

e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
    console.log(intersects[i].face)
}
```

`face` has many built-in methods and gives you the ability to manipulate the face and get info from it. To give you an idea, this is directly copy pasted from my `console.log(intersects[i].face)` output, and is the related to only *one* face (*note*: these are only the top/parental level methods, many of them have more children.).

```
Ac {a: 5307, b: 5308, c: 5309, normal: p, vertexNormals: Array(0), …}
    a: 5307
    b: 5308
    c: 5309
color: D
    __proto__:
    add: ƒ (a)
    addColors: ƒ (a,b)
    addScalar: ƒ (a)
    b: 1
    clone: ƒ ()
    convertGammaToLinear: ƒ (a)
    convertLinearToGamma: ƒ (a)
    convertLinearToSRGB: ƒ ()
    convertSRGBToLinear: ƒ ()
    copy: ƒ (a)
    copyGammaToLinear: ƒ (a,b)
    copyLinearToGamma: ƒ (a,b)
    copyLinearToSRGB: ƒ (a)
    copySRGBToLinear: ƒ (a)
    equals: ƒ (a)
    fromArray: ƒ (a,b)
    g: 1
    getHSL: ƒ (a)
    getHex: ƒ ()
    getHexString: ƒ ()
    getStyle: ƒ ()
    isColor: true
    lerp: ƒ (a,b)
    lerpHSL: ƒ (a,b)
    multiply: ƒ (a)
    multiplyScalar: ƒ (a)
    offsetHSL: ƒ (a,b,c)
    r: 1
    set: ƒ (a)
    setColorName: ƒ (a)
    setHSL: ƒ (a,b,c)
    setHex: ƒ (a)
    setRGB: ƒ (a,b,c)
    setScalar: ƒ (a)
    setStyle: ƒ (a)
    sub: ƒ (a)
    toArray: ƒ (a,b)
    toJSON: ƒ ()
    constructor: ƒ D(a,b,c)
    __proto__: Object
materialIndex: 0
normal: p
    x: 0.9839296339696827
    y: 0
    z: 0.17855664478334757
    __proto__:
    add: ƒ (a,b)
    addScalar: ƒ (a)
    addScaledVector: ƒ (a,b)
    addVectors: ƒ (a,b)
    angleTo: ƒ (a)
    applyAxisAngle: ƒ (a,b)
    applyEuler: ƒ (a)
    applyMatrix3: ƒ (a)
    applyMatrix4: ƒ (a)
    applyNormalMatrix: ƒ (a)
    applyProjection: ƒ (a)
    applyQuaternion: ƒ (a)
    ceil: ƒ ()
    clamp: ƒ (a,b)
    clampLength: ƒ (a,b)
    clampScalar: ƒ (a,b)
    clone: ƒ ()
    copy: ƒ (a)
    cross: ƒ (a,b)
    crossVectors: ƒ (a,b)
    distanceTo: ƒ (a)
    distanceToManhattan: ƒ (a)
    distanceToSquared: ƒ (a)
    divide: ƒ (a)
    divideScalar: ƒ (a)
    dot: ƒ (a)
    equals: ƒ (a)
    floor: ƒ ()
    fromArray: ƒ (a,b)
    fromAttribute: ƒ (a,b,c)
    fromBufferAttribute: ƒ (a,b,c)
    getColumnFromMatrix: ƒ (a,b)
    getComponent: ƒ (a)
    getPositionFromMatrix: ƒ (a)
    getScaleFromMatrix: ƒ (a)
    isVector3: true
    length: ƒ ()
    lengthManhattan: ƒ ()
    lengthSq: ƒ ()
    lerp: ƒ (a,b)
    lerpVectors: ƒ (a,b,c)
    manhattanDistanceTo: ƒ (a)
    manhattanLength: ƒ ()
    max: ƒ (a)
    min: ƒ (a)
    multiply: ƒ (a,b)
    multiplyScalar: ƒ (a)
    multiplyVectors: ƒ (a,b)
    negate: ƒ ()
    normalize: ƒ ()
    project: ƒ (a)
    projectOnPlane: ƒ (a)
    projectOnVector: ƒ (a)
    random: ƒ ()
    reflect: ƒ (a)
    round: ƒ ()
    roundToZero: ƒ ()
    set: ƒ (a,b,c)
    setComponent: ƒ (a,b)
    setEulerFromQuaternion: ƒ ()
    setEulerFromRotationMatrix: ƒ ()
    setFromCylindrical: ƒ (a)
    setFromCylindricalCoords: ƒ (a,b,c)
    setFromMatrix3Column: ƒ (a, b)
    setFromMatrixColumn: ƒ (a,b)
    setFromMatrixPosition: ƒ (a)
    setFromMatrixScale: ƒ (a)
    setFromSpherical: ƒ (a)
    setFromSphericalCoords: ƒ (a,b,c)
    setLength: ƒ (a)
    setScalar: ƒ (a)
    setX: ƒ (a)
    setY: ƒ (a)
    setZ: ƒ (a)
    sub: ƒ (a,b)
    subScalar: ƒ (a)
    subVectors: ƒ (a,b)
    toArray: ƒ (a,b)
    transformDirection: ƒ (a)
    unproject: ƒ (a)
    constructor: ƒ p(a,b, c)
    __proto__: Object
vertexColors: Array(0)
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
vertexNormals: Array(0)
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__:
    clone: ƒ ()
    copy: ƒ (a)
    constructor: ƒ Ac(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

> The raycaster is there, but doesn't seem to be working properly so I have commented it out for the moment.

I have debugged your code locally. Raycasting does not work since `onMouseMove()` is not yet called. You have to register it as an event listener first. So try to add the following line to your example:

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
```

If you then comment in your raycasting code inside the animation loop, the model should become red when hovering with the mouse.

Comment: Updated code accordingly. Also added an extra line of code to change back the color when not hovering over the object.

Comment: Regarding your vertex selection issue: I suggest you read the following topic in the `three.js` forum for some possible solutions: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/highlight-snap-the-vertex-of-geometry-on-mouse-hovering/6347

Comment: Thanks. The working raycaster has also give me good insight on what information it gives about the object it is casting at. (e.g. `console.log(intersects)` has given me great insight). This has given me a lot more information. Once I find a solution, I will post it Q&A style as an answer on my original question.